# vue-i18n with vue-electron : TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, electron, vue-i18n

I building a app for Desktop using `electron.js` + `vue.js` and plugins `vue-electron`, `electron-window-manager`.
Now I need put vue-i18n and it's structure work non default way...

ex. `mainwindow` are like toolbar or main menu. Others menus(windows) are opened by the main menu and with this combination of technologies the `vue-i18n` do not work fine.

this is a repo:
[anderzilla/vue-electron](https://github.com/anderzilla/vue-electron)!

I have tryed solutions like
[vue-i18n tutorial kazupon](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html#yarn)!
but the error message is:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined"

found in

---> <MenuConfig> at src/renderer/components/MenuConfig.vue
       <Clarity> at src/renderer/App.vue
         <Root>
```

and my `i18n.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const messages = {
    'pt' : {
        alterarsenha: 'Alterar Senha',
        grupos: 'Grupos',
        pausas: 'Pausas',
        disponivel: 'Disponibilidade',
        sair: 'Sair',
    },
    'en' : {
        alterarsenha: 'Change Password',
        grupos: 'Groups',
        pausas: 'Pauses',
        disponivel: 'Disponibility',
        sair: 'Logout',
    },
    'es' : {}
};

const i18n = new VueI18n({    
    locale: 'pt', // set locale    
    fallbackLocale: 'en', // set fallback locale    
    messages, // set locale messages
});
```

In main.js code it's like tuto's kazupon

In template (other window created by electron-window-manager)

```
<template>
  <main id="menu-config">
    <v-row>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="menu-config">
        <div class="menu-config">
          <ul @mouseleave="close">
            <li>
             <button @click="alterarSenha" class="titulo" >{{ $t('alterarsenha') }} - Alterar Senha</button>
            </li>
```

the "$t" is the problem...

I only need this for i18n aplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it! The problem is the order that components be declareded.

```
new Vue({ 
components: { App }, 
i18n, 
router, 
store, 
template: "<App/>" 
}).$mount("#app");
```

i18n must be before router!